# Loading javascript file in different endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I'm writing a large javascript app and it's a single page application. I'm using node.js with jade. And I have question about loading javascript files for the front end.

Like you have these pages :

```
- profile
- dashboard
- setting
```

I should load profile.js when the user only come to the profile page correct? I have a layout.html for header and footer, and above pages are children of the layout. I don't want to load everything at the home at once because that will be too heavy.

But my question is am I doing it right by putting my javascript at the bottom of every html file? same go with my css file.

Comment: What are sizes of your minified js files?

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (!document.head.querySelector(".angular-script")) { // Angular is not added yet
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js";
    s.className = "angular-script";
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Load angular</button>

<span ng-app>{{1 + 2 + 3}}</span>
```

> But my question is am I doing it right by putting my javascript at the bottom of every html file? same go with my css file.

1. Usually script in html is not executed. jQuery does it for you, but I still think, it's not a good idea.
2. You are loading the same script multiple times. It would be right to load script for each page not more than once.

Comment: I'm not asking how to load it.